# How find computer in AD by "Verify Caller-ID" value

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I need find computer in Active Directory using "Verify Caller-ID" value in c# aplication.
My currently code:

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(ldap, (string.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(verify caller-id=*{0}*))", "searchValue")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `Verify Caller-ID` you see in the "Dial-In" page of the user dialog in Active Directory Users and Computers is called `msNPCallingStationID` in LDAP.
[msNPCallingStationID attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-msnpcallingstationid)

Try

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(ldap, (string.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(msNPCallingStationID=*{0}*))", "searchValue")));
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I resolved this problem call PowerShell query like 
_"Get-ADComputer -Filter { msNPCallingStationID -like '*" + calliing + "*' -and enabled -eq $true } -Properties * | Select name"_